# why it become a sphere?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I have  some confusion on this [diagram](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/clever-homotopy-equivalences)

It is given  that

[image]

**My confusion** :Here  Im not getting  why it become  a sphere  [image]

**My thinking**[image] :

Comment: I agree. The first drawing suggests that the blue part is removed, but the rest treat the blue line as part of the space. We must be missing some context.

Comment: Ah yeah, it's explained in the article you linked. The space "consists of the space inside the yellow cube including the blue disc, but not including the white boundary of that disc." There's more explanation after that.

Comment: "Notice that our circle sits on some plane in R3. (I've shaded it in dark yellow.) Then all the points lying on that plane outside of the circle (the dark yellow bit) along with the points in R3 not on the plane (the light yellow bit) deformation retract onto a sphere. (So basically, everything that's yellow maps to a sphere.)"

Comment: okay, I didn't read the article.I only see  that diagram @Karl

Comment: @wasiu See in particular the next diagram in the article